# Is there a way to limit a token transfer based on certain conditions?

Tags: solana-program, token

Is there a way to limit a token send transaction based on certain conditions like:

- User must have at least 2 SOL in their balance before the token can be sent.
- User must have this other token in order to send out.
- User must have an account older than 1 month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> User must have at least 2 SOL in their balance before the token can be sent.

In anchor you can use `constraint` e.g.

```
    #[account(constraint = user.to_account_info().lamports > 2000000000)]
    pub user: SystemAccount<'info>,
```

> User must have this other token in order to send out.

You don't need any checks here. If the user has an insufficient balance, the Transfer cpi call will fail and the transaction will fail.

> User must have an account older than 1 month.

Have the users call your program 1 month prior in order to send tokens.

Create a pda `User` account  for each user where you store the data using `Sysvar<'info,Clock>` and then check if `current date - stored date` is superior to `1 month in seconds` e.g. `2,630,000`

Comment: These could work for your own program's instructions, but nothing would stop the user sending the SPL tokens from their own wallet to another recipient and bypassing your program. I think the general answer is probably that you can't enforce these sorts of checks on **all** token transactions, only those done with your own program, but I'm not 100% sure TBH.

Comment: I'm not sure if op meant it that way since there's smart contract tag. But yeah there's no way to limit the sending of tokens. In fact, there's no risk whatsoever of allowing anyone to send to anywhere. e.g. You can always store how much user deposited rather than seeing the balance of token account.

Answer (score 0):

> User must have at least 2 SOL in their balance before the token can be sent.

See the other answer.

> User must have this other token in order to send out.

I think the other answer has misunderstood the requirement. I believe the question is asking about requiring the user to have token of mint A to send token of mint B.

You should be able to [use transfer hooks](https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/transfer-hook) to check this and throw an error if the wallet does not have a balance of the token A.

> User must have an account older than 1 month.

You can check for the oldest transaction on an account in a transfer hook.